# DNS Server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, web-server

Problem: I want to run intranet on my organization, the plate form that I use was ubuntu.

Question: How can I run my own dns server, instead of http://192.168.0.5/?

Comment: nit: platform is one word. Plate form is neat.

Answer (score 4):

Use BIND, and a proper place to ask. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for something much simpler than bind, consider **dnsmasq**. Maintaining the DNS service is as simple as editing /etc/hosts (or another file, at your discretion) and hupping the server. If you are not doing anything fancy with DNS, just listing local hosts, this may be all you need.

Comment: +1 for dnsmasq. It can act as a DHCP server, too

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: sudo apt-get install bind

Long answer: http://linux.justinhartman.com/DNS_Installation_and_Setup_using_BIND9

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your organization's infrastructure, bind is definitely a solid base to build your DNS on. However, you will absolutely need to study up on DNS, how it works, and how to configure bind. It is not as simple as "How do I do this? Do x,y & z and you're done"

DNS really isn't that complicated. Grab an O'Reilly book or dig around on google for some how-to's and you could have it up an running with a simple setup in a matter of an hour.